# Passing inline math to custom choice command

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, exam

I've been playing around with a custom "CorrectChoice" command to add referencing to the answers. Specifically, with this setup, I can reference the correct choice and its corresponding answer easily else where in the text:

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CC[1]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{anst:\thequestion}%
  \CorrectChoice\label{ans:\thequestion} #1
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question This is a question

\begin{choices}
\choice 8
\CC 1
\choice 3
\choice 4
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

The correct answer for question 1 is choice \ref{ans:1}, \ref{anst:1}

\end{document}
```

The above code works wonderfully. The problem is when the argument given to CC is inline math i.e in the form `$...$`

For example

```latex
...
CC $\frac{3}{2}$
...
```

I receive a compile error: ! Missing $ inserted. So I figured I am not handling the arguments passed to the newcommand correctly. I came across \tags at one point when doing some research, but couldn't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\choice` just issues `\item` and does some checks.

Your call should be `\CC{$\frac{3}{2}$}` because you want the text to be grabbed as argument to `\CC`.

In the case of `\CC 1`, the rules of TeX make it grab `1` as the argument; but `\CC 12` would not work.

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CC[1]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{anst:\thequestion}%
  \CorrectChoice\label{ans:\thequestion} #1
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question This is a question

\begin{choices}
\choice 8
\CC{$\frac{3}{2}$}
\choice 3
\choice 4
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

The correct answer for question 1 is choice \ref{ans:1}, \ref{anst:1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That makes complete sense! How does item know how many of the arguments to capture? Does each argument default to one character (thats why 1 is counted, but 12 wouldnt work)?

Comment: @JustinDalrymple `\item` does not grab arguments. It outputs the item number (a letter, in this case) and then does nothing else (well, it does something else, but it's not relevant here); the following text is simply typeset.